# 'simple' scoping issue in socket.IO server

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, socket.io

I have a simple node .js socket.IO server whcihs is working but scoping in my event callbacks is incorrect. How do I properly reference 'client' from within my client.on handler??

```
sockIO.sockets.on('connection', function (client){
  // new client is here!
  console.log('A new user connected!');

  //This WORKS!
   client.emit('news', { msg: 'new user connected from socket server' });

  client.on('customEvent', function (data) {
    console.log('I received a custom event and data = ', data);
     //following doesn't get called also 'client.emit' doesn't work
     this.emit('foo', { msg: 'foo from socket server' });
   });
```

client code

```
<html>
<p id="text">socket.io</p>


<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
                text        = $('#text');
console.log('socket is '+socket);
               socket.on('connect', function () {
             $('#text').html('connected');
        });


         socket.on('news', function (info) {
            $('#text').html(info.msg);

        });
          socket.on('foo', function (info) {
            alert('YES foo received from server');
            $('#text').html(info.msg);

        });

        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
             $('#text').html('disconnected');
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Throws exception or just doesn't resolve?

Comment: never gets called period, or else Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following code:

```
sockIO.sockets.on('connection', function (client) {
    // new client is here!
    console.log('A new user connected!');
    //This WORKS!
    client.emit('news', { msg: 'new user connected from socket server' });
    client.on('customEvent', function (data) {
        console.log('I received a custom event and data = ', data);
        //following doesn't work also 'client.emit' doesn't work
        client.emit('foo', { msg: 'foo from socket server' });
    });
});
```

There is no reason to not get `foo` event send via the socket. The handler of `customEvent` doesn't have `client` variable defined, so it looks in the parent scope and it finds it there. If the `news` event works, then `foo` should work as well. I'll suggest to check the catching of `foo` in the client side. Are you actually listening for such a message?

Comment: But are you actually listening for `foo` events in the client-side? Can you post some client-side js code.

Comment: and if I trace typeof(client.emit) from within my handler it properly traces function...WTF??

Comment: Ok, now I see your client-side code, but I don't see the calling of `customEvent`. This means that your code never enters in `customEvent` handler in the back-end code and `client.emit('foo')` is never called.